# Access to *.doc was denied | Libreoffice 5.4.5.1

Tags: 17.10, libreoffice, 18.04

I am using Ubuntu 17.10 as my daily driver. I have created a separate partition like `home` for storage `/data` of ext4 type.

Today, i updated my system  using `apt dist-upgrade`. It also updated  libreoffice after updating libreoffice, i am unable to access all my documents from `/data` partition only and start getting the below error

[image]

Note:- I am able to access documents from `home` directory.

When i am trying to create new document using libreoffice getting below error

[image]

Comment: Use my `pathlld` script: https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld.git - Bash script to answer "Why can't I read/write that file?" to check the permissions, mount status, etc.

Comment: Can you access to this file from your terminal ? Can you add the output of the following command ? `ls -l /data/Tutorials/My\ Notes/Bookmarks.docx`

Comment: I am able to access same before update. there is no change in permissions.   I am not able to create any new file as well using libreoffice rest of the applications like gedit working fine.

Comment: ```-rwxr-xr-x 1 sandeep sandeep 10749 Feb 21 15:05 /data/Tutorials/My Notes/Bookmarks.docx```

Comment: try 'ls -ltr Notes/Bookmarks.docx'.  check is your username and group matchs.

Comment: yes it matches, as i commented above this issue is only related to libreoffice rest of the app working fine. ```-rwxr-xr-x 1 sandeep sandeep 10749 Feb 21 15:05 /data/Tutorials/My Notes/Bookmarks.docx```

Comment: Same problem here ... New Libre Office can't open files that were recently created and were previously opened by Libre Office. Terminal application (such as 'cat') and other GUI application such as Geany editor, can open these files, but Libre Office say: access was denied. I uninstalled Libre Office and installed the most recent version and yet also the new Libre Office (5.4.5.1) won't open some of the files. Their chmod permission was set to 777 and yet it says 'access was denied' ...

Comment: This looks like a bug in LibreOffice and its apparmor rules.  You should probably file a bug on Launchpad about this.

Comment: A possible workaround is to move the file to another partition (say /tmp) and open from there (and then move back if needed).

Comment: There seems to already be a bug filed on Launchpad, here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice/+bug/1751005/

Comment: I am facing this issue on a ext4 mounted filesystem. It started just today when I tried to open some csv files with Calc.

Answer (score 0):

I first recommended a temporary Workaround: Copy your file to $HOME.

However, it's probably better to solve the problem like is described in the answer to my own question:
[Libreoffice 5.4.5.1 gets access denied on NFS mounted filesystem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1008880/libreoffice-5-4-5-1-gets-access-denied-on-nfs-mounted-filesystem)

Answer (score 0):

Issue is fixed finally after latest update.