# Libreoffice 5.4.5.1 gets access denied on NFS mounted filesystem

Tags: 17.10, libreoffice, apparmor

Using Ubuntu 17.10 and Libreoffice I've updated everything today.
Trying to open .od_ documents from my /Documents folder now yields "Access denied" 
(see also question [[Access to *.doc was denied | Libreoffice 5.4.5.1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1008741/access-to-doc-was-denied-libreoffice-5-4-5-1][1]))

/Documents in my case is mounted via NFS.

Copying a document from the NFS filesystem to the local $HOME works and the copied document can be opened with Libreoffice.
So the bug seems to affect only network or removable filesystems.

Edit: Structured the question and moved the solution to a separate answer

Comment: It would be better if you edit your question to have **only** the question and then post your solution as the answer. That is encouraged here. And this issue is affecting quite a few users.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But my reputation is 0 and I could not post my solution as answer to the already existing question. But I'll try to modify this.

Comment: Please read https://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer. You have the requisite reputation to answer your own question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Searching the Internet I found a thread in Ubuntu One presenting the solution: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice/+bug/1751005/comments/10
As far as I understood the lengthy discussion it has to do with the apparmor protection.
What I finally did and what helped me (did not understand why :(

```
sudo ln -s /etc/apparmor.d/usr.lib.libreoffice.program.* /etc/apparmor.d/disable/
```

But now restarting the apparmor service yields a failure.So I had to search again and this solved my 2nd problem.

```
sudo apt-get install apparmor-easyprof-ubuntu
```

However, libreoffice still could not open my files. So I rebooted. After reboot I checked the state of apparmor

```
sudo service apparmor status
```

delivering

```
apparmor.service - AppArmor initialization
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apparmor.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Thu 2018-02-22 23:43:41 CET; 47min ago
     Docs: man:apparmor(7)
           http://wiki.apparmor.net/
  Process: 945 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apparmor start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 945 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 0 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 0B
      CPU: 0
   CGroup: /system.slice/apparmor.service

Feb 22 23:43:41 lnx54srv14 systemd[1]: Starting AppArmor initialization...
Feb 22 23:43:41 lnx54srv14 apparmor[945]:  * Starting AppArmor profiles
Feb 22 23:43:41 lnx54srv14 apparmor[945]: Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.bin.firefox
Feb 22 23:43:41 lnx54srv14 apparmor[945]: Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.lib.libreoffice.program.oosplash
Feb 22 23:43:41 lnx54srv14 apparmor[945]: Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.lib.libreoffice.program.senddoc
Feb 22 23:43:41 lnx54srv14 apparmor[945]: Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.lib.libreoffice.program.soffice.bin
Feb 22 23:43:41 lnx54srv14 apparmor[945]: Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.lib.libreoffice.program.xpdfimport
Feb 22 23:43:41 lnx54srv14 apparmor[945]: Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.sbin.rsyslogd
Feb 22 23:43:41 lnx54srv14 apparmor[945]:    ...done.
Feb 22 23:43:41 lnx54srv14 systemd[1]: Started AppArmor initialization.
```

**And surprisingly Libreoffice now works again on all my NFS mounted documents.**

But may be you should check remark #18 and more to come on launchpad. They might present another (better?) solution: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice/+bug/1751005/comments/18

Answer (score 3):

Temporary solution till the reboot (see this bug [libreoffice cannot open a document not within $HOME](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice/+bug/1751005)):

```
sudo apparmor_parser -R /etc/apparmor.d/usr.lib.libreoffice.program.*
```

Permanent solution to disable user profiles:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/apparmor.d/usr.lib.libreoffice.program.* /etc/apparmor.d/disable/
```

Answer (score 0):

For evince I solved this issue by adding following line to AppArmor profile /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.evince :

```
 owner /path/to/mounted/filesystem/**  rw,
```

Followed by

```
sudo apparmor_parser -r /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.evince
```

to reread the configuration.